# Accessing product price in template.php

Tags: 7, theming, ubercart

So I am using hook_form_alter to alter the add-to-cart button for my Ubercart pages. See here:

```
function hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ( !empty($form['nid']) ) {
    $node = $form['nid']['#value'];
  }
  else {
    $node = 0;
  }

  if (($form_id == 'uc_product_add_to_cart_form_'.$node) and ($form['node']['#value']->type =='product')){

    hide($form['actions']['submit']);

    $form['button'] = array(
      '#prefix' => '<button type="submit" id="edit-submit-'. $node .'" name="op" class="node-add-to-cart btn btn-cart">',
      '#suffix' => '</button>',
      '#markup' => 'Buy for: ',
      '#weight' => 1,
    );
  }
}
```

This works great. Except, in my form['button'] array, want to change the button markup to something like: 'Buy for: $10'.

How can I access the node's list and selling price so that I can use it in the markup of the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The node object is made available through the `$form` array in `$form['node']['#value']`. You can find list & sell price through the `$form['node']['#value']->list_price` & `$form['node']['#value']->sell_price` properties.

Comment: Thanks Shawn! It half-works. If my product's price is $10, the output I get on my product node page is: 10.00000, rather than just '$10' as I need. Any ideas? Thanks for your time

Comment: The property property is stored as a float. If you want to display it as an integer you can cast it (e.g. `(int) $form['node']['#value']->sell_price`) or round it 2 decimals (e.g. `round($form['node']['#value']->sell_price, 2)` ) in the event you'll need fractional pricing.

Comment: Thank you Shawn, that worked. I have one more question though... how can I display the store currency with the price, other than just printing a dollar sign? Is there an easy method to show the current currency before that pricing?

Comment: That I don't know. I've never had to use Ubercart in an international/multi-currency setup. That be better asked as separate question.